# iOS: RestKit loadObject & send params

Tags: objective-c, ios, parameters, restkit

using loadObjectAtResourcePath on GET method, doesn't include my parameters on the requests.

for example, if I send:

```
[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://something/ws"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/res" delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"val", @"param1",
                              nil];
        loader.params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:dict];
    }];
```

the final url request doesn't include the "?param1=val" part - why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update Months Later**

The real answer is that `loader.params` creates the `HTTP BODY`, hence it works for `POST, PUT, DELETE` etc but not for `GET` where the **params are appended to the URL.**

Hence, the answer below still works if you're facing the same issue for `GET`, but if you're sending out `GET` requests, it's mostly using methods that attach the params to the query string.

To summarize the differences between the two.

**Sending params in the HTTP Body**(i.e. `POST, UPDATE, DELETE`)

```
// Convert a NS Dictionary into Params
RKParams *params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:optionValues];

// I use sendObject to skip the router. Otherwise it's normally postObject
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:yourObject toResourcePath: yourResourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.delegate = delegate;
    loader.params = params; // This sets params in the POST body and discards your yourObject mapping

} ];
```

**Caveat Emptor (for above)**

Setting params in the block destroys any mapping that you might have set in `yourObject`, kind of defeats the purpose of using object mapping. There's a fix here by Sebastian [loader.params - Extra params](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/restkit/E-mQkZ-d_hY/eKZvtgQTcC0J) if you really want to use this method to append extra parameters to your Post not in the object.

**Sending in params as Query String** (i.e. `GET`)

```
// Make a NS dictionary and use stringByAppendingQueryParameters
NSDictionary *shopParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
                                @"limit",@"20", 
                                @"location",@"latitude,longitude",
                                nil];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/v1/shops.json" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:shopParams] delegate:objectDelegate];
```

The rest of the answer is just for reference, I'm a hoarder.

---

**Old Answer**

I'm using RestKit for my project and facing the same issue.

I think `RKParams` is mainly used to do `POST` requests. I cannot fully decipher your code because 1) I don't know `loader`'s declaration? 2) `RKParams` is not to be used with `Object Manager`?

I did this.

**Loader Method in App Delegate**

```
NSDictionary *shopParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"limit",@"30", nil]; 

[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/api/v1/shops.json" queryParams:shopParams delegate:self];
```

**Delegate**

```
- (void)requestDidStartLoad:(RKRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"RK Request description: %@",[request description]);
}
```

**Output**:
`RK Request description: <RKRequest: 0x7993db0>` and rails log say `{"limit"=>"30"}`.

From the autocomplete in Xcode, you can see the `get` request didn't even use `RKParams`. Just a `NSDict`. The POST requests uses it.

My goal is to attach a query string, i.e. `?location=singapore&etcetc` to my API methods in Rails. For this, RK comes with a `NSString` addon called `appendQueryParams` [RK docs link](http://restkit.org/api/0.9.3/Categories/NSString(NSString).html#//api/name/appendQueryParams:) that you can use to append query params.

If your goal is `POST` images etc, you can follow the above line of thought of using `RKClient`.

**Update:**

**If you just want to append parameters to Object Manager**

```
 NSDictionary *shopParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
                                @"limit",@"20", 
                                @"location",@"latitude,longitude",
                                nil];
```

**This is outdated and marked for deprecation.**

---

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/v1/shops.json" appendQueryParams:shopParams] delegate:self];
```

---

**Use this instead:**

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/api/v1/shops.json stringByAppendingQueryParameters:shopParams] delegate:yourLoaderDelegate];
```

**Rails Log**: `{"location"=>"latitude,longitude", "limit"=>"20"}`

Hope in my answer I didn't make any wrong statements.

Refer to this question [RestKit GET query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227255/restkit-get-query-parameters).

Comment: Eventually it's what I did too. I did however wanted to use the object manager to use the mapping feature of RestKit.

Comment: @daemonsy Thanks a bunch for this. I've been banging my head against it for a while.

Comment: @drewish Thanks. Everytime someone finds this useful, I'll try to update it to be a bit more thorough.